# Find matching Rows in same MS SQL table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to find all rows with the same address using Last as the criterion, however, if someone lives at the same address with a different last name I need them returned too.

Simplified version of my table below

```
ID      Last     Addr
----    ----    -----
1      Smith    123 Fake St
2      Smith    123 Fake St
3      Fox      123 Fake St
4      Jones    111 Jones Rd
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Addr IN
         (SELECT Addr
          FROM Table AS T
          GROUP BY Addr
          HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1)
       AND Last = 'Smith'
```

This returns IDs 1 and 2 but I also need it to return ID 3 because the address is the the same.  I understand it isn't returning because Last doesn't match in my WHERE statement, however, I would only have Last when I search and need to know everyone else at the same address regardless of their name.

Comment: `AND Last = 'Smith'` is outside of your subquery; move it inside the subquery's brackets; i.e. between the second `FROM TABLE` statement and the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: moving it inside the subquery actually returned less results; I'm no expert so IDK why but it didn't work.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER()`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Addr)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE A
WHERE N > 1
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
           WHERE Last = 'Smith'
           AND Addr = A.Addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a count and group by, anything with more than 1 is a repeat

```
select ID, Last, Addr, count(1) num from table group by ID, Last, Addr
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table AS t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM Table 
               WHERE Addr = t.Addr AND Last = 'Smith');
```

Here is a running sample:

```
declare @Table table (ID int, [Last] nvarchar(50), Addr nvarchar(50));

insert into @Table values
(1, 'Smith', '123 Fake St'),
(2, 'Smith', '123 Fake St'),
(3, 'Fox', '123 Fake St'),
(4, 'Jones', '111 Jones Rd');

SELECT *
FROM @Table AS t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM @Table 
               WHERE Addr = t.Addr AND Last = 'Smith');

/* Result
ID Last     Addr
-- -------- -----------------------
1  Smith    123 Fake St
2  Smith    123 Fake St
3  Fox      123 Fake St
*/
```

Comment: This returns an empty set.

Comment: I apologize, I may have typed the query wrong, however, this is returning extra rows.  I am getting all the Smiths including those with no duplicate addresses.  After re-reading my question I don't think I made that clear.  I am going to accept Lamak's answer as it gives me what I need, however, this is good too.